# C++ - writing directly to memory(Kernel)

Tags: c++, windows, memory, kernel

I have asked pretty much the same thing before, but my post got deleted for some reason.

Anyway, I'm trying to use C++ and write a program that allows me to access directly to the memory and write stuff to it. I heard I need to do something with the kernel as that is a "bridge" that connects the OS and application (I think). Is there anyway I can download some sdk for the kernel?

I've said this in my previous post (which got deleted after some time) that the reason to this is because I want to try and crash windows 7 as my professor at university asked me to. (so please don't ask me stuff like "why do you want to crash windows?" or something along those lines...)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to crash Windows ?... Sorry, couldn't resist :/

Comment: You need to examine your eye for asking that question... Sorry, just got to say it :/

Comment: Would a bluescreen be enough?

Comment: yes, that would be enough lol I don't want to damage the pc too much

Comment: You don't need an SDK to write to kernel memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interesting in working with the kernel, you're likely looking for the Windows Driver Kit, found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428

It has a variety of lower-level tools and headers to help you write drivers and other kernel-mode code.

Typical programs obviously don't have carte blanche access to memory, while drivers have more control (although I would guess they use the system's memory management as well, not entirely sure). You'll find more information in the WDK.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) this will surely help me :)

Answer (score 3):

[Write a driver](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=20), make it crash. Of course, in only very specific circumstances will this actually make Windows 7 crash (because, unlike the public opinion, it wasn't written by total idiots).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RtlSetProcessIsCritical function in order to flag that your process is critical for system operations.

If your process is terminated (for example if your application calls ExitProcess) a bluescreen will appear. In order to use this function you need to enable the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege.